# tcolorbox vs KOMAoptions: TeX capacity exceed

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, tcolorbox, grouping

I tried to put a box around a definition, but got an error. The problem is, I am using a huge template, so I do not really understand most of the settings.

If I add this to my file:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=bla]
blu
\end{tcolorbox}
```

LaTeX tells me "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]".

If I comment out the following lines, it works, but since I have no idea what they do exactly I would prefer not to touch them, as otherwise I might have to read the whole document again:

```
\KOMAoptions{
     parskip=relative,  % change indentation according to fontsize (recommanded)
   %parskip=absolute, % do not change indentation according to fontsize
   parskip=false        % indentation of 1em
   % parskip=true       % parksip of 1 line - with free space in last line of 1em
   % parskip=full-      % parksip of 1 line - no adjustment
   % parskip=full+      % parksip of 1 line - with free space in last line of 1/4
   % parskip=full*      % parksip of 1 line - with free space in last line of 1/3
   % parskip=half       % parksip of .5line - with free space in last line of 1em
   % parskip=half-      % parksip of .5line - no adjustment
   % parskip=half+      % parksip of .5line - with free space in last line of 1/3
   % parskip=half*      % parksip of .5line - with free space in last line of 1em
}
```

It SEEMS to me that I would not change much, but some packages seem to be loaded only once others are loaded and so on. So to come to end end with my rambling - what happens here!?

Comment: Actually, you can provide a minimal example: it just will take time to construct it. It will also probably be tedious and annoying to do so: that's the nature of the game, sometimes. (Make a copy of the file; then slowly comment out bit by bit.)  However, that might still be quicker than getting a answer because someone just automagically knows the solution.  I also suspect (not promise) that almost all of the three-file preamble is unneeded, but it depends how they are organized....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I will be doing it first thing tomorrow morning (as there is really nothing left to do :/), but I already have seen miracles like this here, so maybe someone is faster with the answer :)

Comment: It is easy to make a MWE giving that error, but start with a copy of your document until that is all it does, for example this document: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\z{\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup\bgroup}
\def\zz{\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z}
\zz\zz\zz

\end{document}`

Comment: Your edits don't really help as the document is now complete but is error free.

Comment: That example is minimal, but it doesn't show the problem so it is not helpful for finding the problem. You need to work from the file that is causing the problems.  Start by commenting out some of the text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Once you have isolated the relevant chunk, then you can try to remove superfluous preamble elements. (E.g., it is unlikely to be related to your fonts.)

Comment: Since we can't see the source of the problem, we can't really identify a solution for it (the above code compiles perfectly). However, with some "TeX capacity exceeded" errors for which I was unable to find an exact cause, adding `\usepackage{etex}` to the beginning of my document (preambule, right after `\begin{document}`) sometimes solved the issue.
If this MWE example does not compile flawlessly on your computer, you might want to consider reinstalling your LaTeX distribution.

Comment: I took the document apart and found the conflicting lines. Still clueless though why they do not like each other or what to do apart from commenting them out.

Comment: Now you have a MWE that produces an error! `\documentclass[parskip=relative]{scrreprt} \usepackage{tcolorbox} \begin{document} \begin{tcolorbox}[title=bla] blu \end{tcolorbox} \end{document}` <-- This is what (ideally) your question should use to help others get to work on the problem.

Comment: Note that the value `relative` is not explained in the [KOMA-Script documention](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf). In the German KOMA-Script book it is mentioned that this value is experimentell and may not working as expected on every time.

Comment: @jon the example from your last comment compiles just fine without any errors or warnings whatsoever!

Comment: @clemens -- Well, I don't remember this conversation very well, but I believe my point was that an M(N)WE should be minimal in the way I showed, not that that was itself the example. I thought the OP would add back in "the conflicting lines" to the MWE I provided in the comment.  I'm guessing the OP found the solution and never posted back....

Comment: @jon sorry: I was absent-minded, I guess: I mistook you for the OP

Comment: @esdd Do you see any point in answering that question, or is it too unclear?

Comment: @Johannes_B I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @esdd Voted as unclear.